# How to empty and insert data in codeigniter driven mysql table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Currently the code gets data from csv file and imports it into relevant mysql table. There are several tables. It inserts data if the table is empty. If data is already present it updates it. I have one specific table within database which has to be emptied every time before inserting or updating data into it. I am not able to achieve it. This is the original code.

```
This is the original code.

        $records = $this->csvimport->parse_csv($this->directory . $file);

        foreach ($records as $row) {
            $data = $this->$function($row);
            
            $data = $this->correct_date_format($data);
            
            foreach ($this->$condition($data) as $column) {
                $this->db->where($column, $data[$column]);
            }

            if ($this->db->get($table, 1)->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($this->$condition($data) as $column) {
                    $this->db->where($column, $data[$column]);
                }

                $this->db->update($table, $data);

            } else {
                $this->db->insert($table, $data);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(['Last_record' => $this->db->where('date', $data['date'])->get($table)->result_array()]);
```

The table name is gap_up. Below is the code change that I did.  But its not working as I expected. It just deletes the table content but new data isnt getting inserted.

```
$records = $this->csvimport->parse_csv($this->directory . $file);

        foreach ($records as $row) {
            $data = $this->$function($row);
            
            $data = $this->correct_date_format($data);
            
            foreach ($this->$condition($data) as $column) {
                $this->db->where($column, $data[$column]);
            }

            if ($this->db->get($table, 1)->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($this->$condition($data) as $column) {
                    $this->db->where($column, $data[$column]);
                }
                $this->db->empty_table('gap_up');
                $this->db->insert(gap_up, $data);
                $this->db->update($table, $data);

            } else {
                $this->db->insert($table, $data);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(['Last_record' => $this->db->where('date', $data['date'])->get($table)->result_array()]);
```

Comment: I cannot make sense of what you are trying to achieve. On each iteration you check to see if $data exists in target `$table`, and if it does you empty `gap_up` and insert one row. So, on the next iteration, if it's an update to `$table`, empty `gap_up` again (deleting row inserted in previous iteration), and insert the data which is going to be updated in `$table`.

Comment: // if it does you empty gap_up and insert one row// The table is getting emptied but the insertion isn't happening. Data should get emptied in the table and new data should be inserted on every run. Unable to get it done.

Comment: // $this->db->empty_table('gap_up');//  this command isnt working. i entered it below $records outside the first for loop.. but its not working.

Comment: Insert command works separately.. When I use both empty table and insert then only emptying part happens.

Answer (score 0):

As [CI_DB_query_builder::insert()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#LC1650) calls [CI_DB_query_builder::_reset_write()](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#LC2795) internally, you need to setup your where conditions for the update after the `insert()` call:

```php
if ($this->db->get($table, 1)->num_rows() > 0) {

    $this->db->empty_table('gap_up');
    $this->db->insert('gap_up', $data);

    foreach ($this->$condition($data) as $column) {
        $this->db->where($column, $data[$column]);
    }
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

} else {
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);
}
```

This still means that your `gap_up` table will only contain one row, as you are deleting everything before inserting each row.

This *intended* update is pointless, as it would just run `UPDATE $table SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2' WHERE col1 = 'val1' AND col2 = 'val2';`, which has no impact. Although, I may be wrong about this, as we cannot see what your variable method `$this->$condition()` is and/or does. Is it excluding some columns?